# interpolation point by pixels

Tags: math, line, interpolation

I need to offset one point on line by pixels.

```
public static function interpolate(pt1:Point, pt2:Point, f:Number):Point
{
     var x:Number = f * pt1.x + (1 - f) * pt2.x;
     var y:Number = f * pt1.y + (1 - f) * pt2.y;

     return new Point(x, y);
}
```

This function can interpolate point by percent if "f" is 0.5 the point will be in the center of line pt1 pt2. Is there a way to make this with pixels?

Comment: Can you explain what problem you're having? A pixel is a point on a screen, so any function that works on a point should work on a pixel.

Comment: :) I mean that I want to pass number of pixels for offset like +32px offset on the line

Comment: OK, it sounds like you're using pixels as a unit of measurement. I think I understand now. So you want to find the coordinates of a point lying between pt1 and pt2, 32 pixels away from pt1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it sounds like you want to write a method `interpolate(pt1, pt2, distanceFromPt1)`. Your existing `interpolate` method does something similar, so you can use the latter to implement the former.

Right now, if you call `interpolate(A,B,f)`, you get a point D where `(distanceBetween(A,D) / distanceBetween(A,B)) == 1-f`. In the version of interpolate you want to write, you don't know what `f` should be, but you can solve for it, because you know `distanceBetween(A,D)`.

```
function iterpolateByDistance(A, B, distanceFromA){
    //(dist(A,D) / dist(A,B)) == 1-f
    //f + (dist(A,D) / dist(A,B)) == 1
    //f == 1 - (dist(A,D) / dist(A,B))
    f = 1 - (distanceFromPt1 / distanceBetween(A, B));
    return interpolate(A, B, f);
}
```

Comment: I tried this before but when you have A,B lets say 1200px and you find what percent of this is 30px you get very small number and it is not working properly. Computer just can not calculate distance properly

Comment: Works perfectly on my machine. What is your value for `f` when the points are (0,0) and (0,1200), and `distanceFromA` is 30? It should be 0.975.

Comment: I'm sorry my mistake it work perfectly I had another issue which causes the problem